# Kubuntu Live USB is unbelievably slow

Tags: boot, usb, kubuntu, live-usb, fat32

I want to install Kubuntu on my PC. Download image, flash to USB with FAT32. But when I boot, it takes 20 minutes to just load the desktop background. There were another 2 flashes to this USB. The first one was Ubuntu, and it was perfectly fine. Then I put Kubuntu on the USB with an unknown app, and it got a bunch of FS errors (the app is BalenaEtcher, so don't use it). Then, Rufus + FAT32 = this slow image. What could be the reason of such slow Kubuntu? I know, this USB's age is ~7 years (the only one I have for the system images), but on the first flash it was perfect. So this speed is anomalous. How to fix this (except buying a new stick)?

## Specifics

- Release: Kubuntu 22.04 LTS
- Stick: Sony 8 GB, ~7 years old
- Motherboard (PC): MSI MAG Bazooka B560M MS-7D18 2.0
- RAM: 16 GB

Comment: You've devoid of actual specifics, but there are cases where some hardware with *firmware bugs* cause certain Ubuntu releases (inc. *flavors*) to boot slower (>10 mins slower) due to the bugs in firmware.. Fix is either correct bugs in firmware (*I have boxes where HP have said they won't fix*) OR re-format the ISO so it avoids the issue, or just be patient..   This is especially noticeable on releases >20.04 but you didn't provide specifics.  The issue only impacts initial boot & install, **not** the installed system.

Comment: I'll provide a page where I write about some issues (https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/slow-boot-times-of-lubuntu-22-04-lts-on-some-hardware/3280) which impacts all Ubuntu ISOs of the same release equally... you'll find posts on this site too..   Yes you can write the ISO in different ways to avoid the various *firmware* issues & it'll boot faster BUT the ISO may not boot on other boxes & personally I don't think its worth it.. most of us only boot a *live* ISO once (*to install & as stated the issue doesn't impact installed system*)

Comment: @guiverc added some specs to the post